# Calculating probability of prizes being distributed at random?

Tags: probability

There are 10 people and 12 prizes. There are 6 x 100 dollars, 3 x 150 dollars and 3 x 200 dollars. The prizes are distributed at random.

a) What is the probability of Person A getting $100?

b) Will Person A have a higher expected return if he colludes with Person B and Person C, such that they will share their prizes equally?

I've calculated that the worse case scenario is all 3 of them getting 100 dollars only, the probability being 6/12 * 5/11 * 4/10 = 9%. But there seems to be something missing.

Do I have to consider them being further down the line, for example 6/11 * 5/10 * 4/9?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Here, we like questions to include your own thoughts on the problem, and more people would be willing to help you if you include what you tried so far or saying what it is that is getting you stuck

Answer (score 1):

Consider the single player $A$ first. He get $\$100$ with probability $\frac12$, $\$150$ with probability $\frac14$ and $\$200$ with probability $\frac14$. Expected return is 
$$
\mathbb E[A] = 100\cdot \frac12+150\cdot \frac14+200 \cdot\frac14 = 137.5.
$$
If playes $A$, $B$, $C$ cooperate, they can get three $\$100$ prizes, or three $\$150$ prizes,  or three $\$200$ prizes, or two $\$100$ and one $\$150$ prizes, or ... 
Sure, we can calculate the expected return directly. Note that there are $10$ cases.

Say, 
$$\mathbb P(\$100\times 3) = \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{12}{3}}=\frac1{11},$$ 
$$\mathbb P(\$100\times 2+\$150) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{12}{3}}=\frac9{44},$$ 
and so on. And then expected return is 
$$
\mathbb E[A_2]=\frac13\left(3\cdot 100 \cdot\frac{1}{11}+(2\cdot 100+150)\cdot\frac{1}{44}+\ldots\right)
$$
Here $A_2$ denotes total return of $A$ if he cooperates.
This is not the best way.

Denote by $B$ and $C$ return of players $B$ and $C$ in the game. $A$, $B$ and $C$ are identically distributed (but dependent). So
$$
\mathbb E[A_2] = \mathbb E\left[\frac{A+B+C}{3}\right] = \frac{\mathbb E[A]+\mathbb E[B]+\mathbb E[C]}{3} = \frac{3\mathbb E[A]}{3} = \mathbb E[A]
$$
So the cooperation results the same expected value as in the single play.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to get my head around one question. Isn't the probability of getting 100 dollars by yourself higher than getting 100 dollars each as a group?

Comment: Yes, the probability of getting 100 dollars by single player is $1/2$ and is much higher than $1/11$. Newertheless average returns are coincide.